# showing multiple values of an object in a row

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I am having a List of objects in my activity class.
want to show objects in a list containing attributes of the object in a row.

for example :

a.1 a.2 a.3 a.4

b.1 b.2 b.3 b.4

c.1 c.2 c.3 c.4

.....

.....

vertically the list should be scrollable.

for showing single value in a row I am sucessfully using :
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.project_list,titles));

Kindly suggest the available solutions.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to do that just go to these like at list for me it worked ok http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/

Happy Coding